# Trying to build a form in Symfony3 using a relational database and keep getting null or invalid type errors

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I have a table that has nullable id fields for other tables, when trying to build a form I keep getting errors that the fields are the wrong type or are null, even before the form is built.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error I am getting "Type error: Return value of AppBundle\Entity\Item::getIdcategory() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Category, null returned"

I have been googling for the last hour trying to find what I am doing wrong.

Controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/intake/addItem/{id}", name="intake_addItem")
 */
public function addItemAction($id, Request $request)    {
  $donor=$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Donor')
    ->find($id);
  $types=$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Types')
    ->findAll();
  $categories=$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
    ->findAll();
  $CW=$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Cardwheel')
    ->findBy(array('idyear'=>'1')); 
  $raffle=$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Raffle')
    ->findBy(array('idyear'=>'1')); 

  $Item = new Item;


  $form =$this->createFormBuilder($Item)
    ->add('Description', Type\TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )
    ->add('Startingbid', Type\TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )
    ->add('BidIncrement', Type\TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )
    ->add('ItemValue', Type\TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )
    ->add('ItemNumber', Type\TextType::class, ['attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )
    ->add('idcategory', EntityType::class, ['class' => Category::class, 'attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )
    ->add('Save', Type\SubmitType::class, ['attr' => ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']]  )
    ->getForm();

  $form->handleRequest($request);

  if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $this->addFlash('notice', 'Item Added');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('intake_listItems');
  }
    return $this->render('intake/addForm.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView(),'Article'=>'Item'));
}
```

Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Item", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fkYear_idx", columns={"idYear"}), @ORM\Index(name="fkItemCategory_idx", columns={"idCategory"}), @ORM\Index(name="fkItemType_idx", columns={"idType"}), @ORM\Index(name="fkItemCardWheel_idx", columns={"idCardWheel"}), @ORM\Index(name="fkItemRaffle_idx", columns={"idRaffle"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Item
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idRaffle", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $idraffle;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Description", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="StartingBid", type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $startingbid;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="BidIncrement", type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $bidincrement;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ItemValue", type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $itemvalue;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ItemNumber", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $itemnumber;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idItem", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $iditem;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Cardwheel
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Cardwheel")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idCardWheel", referencedColumnName="idCardWheel")
 * })
 */
private $idcardwheel;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idCategory", referencedColumnName="idCategory")
 * })
 */
private $idcategory;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Types
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Types")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idType", referencedColumnName="idType")
 * })
 */
private $idtype;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Event
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idYear", referencedColumnName="idYear")
 * })
 */
private $idyear;

public function getIdraffle() {
  return $this->idraffle;
}

public function getDescription() {
  return $this->description;
}

public function getStartingbid() {
  return $this->startingbid;
}

public function getBidincrement() {
  return $this->bidincrement;
}

public function getItemvalue() {
  return $this->itemvalue;
}

public function getItemnumber() {
  return $this->itemnumber;
}

public function getIditem() {
  return $this->iditem;
}

public function getIdcardwheel(): \AppBundle\Entity\Cardwheel {
  return $this->idcardwheel;
}

public function getIdcategory(): \AppBundle\Entity\Category {
  return $this->idcategory;
}

public function getIdtype(): \AppBundle\Entity\Types {
  return $this->idtype;
}

public function getIdyear(): \AppBundle\Entity\Event {
  return $this->idyear;
}

public function setIdraffle($idraffle) {
  $this->idraffle = $idraffle;
}

public function setDescription($description) {
  $this->description = $description;
}

public function setStartingbid($startingbid) {
  $this->startingbid = $startingbid;
}

public function setBidincrement($bidincrement) {
  $this->bidincrement = $bidincrement;
}

public function setItemvalue($itemvalue) {
  $this->itemvalue = $itemvalue;
}

public function setItemnumber($itemnumber) {
  $this->itemnumber = $itemnumber;
}

public function setIditem($iditem) {
  $this->iditem = $iditem;
}

public function setIdcardwheel(\AppBundle\Entity\Cardwheel $idcardwheel) {
  $this->idcardwheel = $idcardwheel;
}

public function setIdcategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $idcategory) {
  $this->idcategory = $idcategory;
}

public function setIdtype(\AppBundle\Entity\Types $idtype) {
  $this->idtype = $idtype;
}

public function setIdyear(\AppBundle\Entity\Event $idyear) {
  $this->idyear = $idyear;
}


}
```

I found a work around by building the form on a blank array instead of an instance of the Item Entity.

```
  $Blank=[];  
  $form =$this->createFormBuilder($Blank)
```

Comment: You already answered your question! you got a table which has nullable id fields!

Comment: Ali, no, I did not answer my own question Why can I not build the form to look for a value, there is no entry even made at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you are using PHP 7 to explicitly declare what the datatype is you are returning in the getIdCategory function. However when there is no category it tries to return NULL, since NULL is not a \AppBundle\Entity\Category object it is throwing an error telling that you specified a return type, but a different type is being returned. if you delete ": \AppBundle\Entity\Category" this error should go away, or in php 7.1 you can use a [nullable return type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)

Comment: Problem is there are categories that should be populating a drop down list.

Comment: according to this https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html you should be doing something slightly different for your EntityType Class call

Comment: Even when I edited it to look the same, I get the same results.
    ->add('idcategory', EntityType::class, ['class' => Category::class,'choice_label'=> 'name' , 'attr' => ['class'=> 'form-control']]  )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getIdcategory(): \AppBundle\Entity\Category {
  if($this->idcategory == null) $this->idcategory = new Category();
  return $this->idcategory;
}
```

actually best practice for relation is not set nullable, just let symfony do empty relation.